# library Jenkins Step is not working to dynamically load methods

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

I want to create a new instance of a class which is in src folder in my shared library. Of cource I can do a simple `def object = new myClass()` with an `import` on the top but I want to do it dynamically initiate classes (trying to use `Class.forName` failed for me and I'm not going to use that solution).

I'm trying to do this from a groovy file which is under `vars` folder and not `src`.
So what I do is : `def customized = library("mySharedLib").com.x.x.MyClass.new(this)`

As it is specified in the documentation for Shared libraries : [Step library](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps-global-lib/#library-load-a-shared-library-on-the-fly)

But I'm getting the error :

`java.lang.IllegalAccessException: com.x.x.MyClass was defined in file:///Path/to/master/workspace/jobs/project/builds/297/libs/mySharedLib/vars/generic.groovy which was not inside file:///Path/to/master/workspace/jobs/project/branches/PR-50/builds/297/libs/mySharedLib/src/`

In the Jenkins Jira [Here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42730), there is the same issue... any ideas ?? I can't understand wht is going on! I tried making a method in a class under `src` folder that does the step library call but it returns same error.

Comment: I‘d assume that you cannot use the library loader until the whole library has been loaded. Did you try using two separate libraries already? Would be curios whether this works.

Answer (score 2):

No need to load the library from within the vars folder (I assume it’s in the same repository like the src folder). Simply import the class with a plain import and use it like in plain groovy, e.g.

```
import org.pack.Myclass
def call() {
    def myClass = new MyClass()
}
```

Comment: Did you really read all the question? I have already said : Of cource I can do a simple def object = new myClass() with an import on the top but I want to dynamically  ! mean I don't know the name of the class.

Comment: In that case I misinterpret your intention. Looks we still need a solution then :(

Comment: Hope the answer still helps some other guys, though :)